# The ratio of cost price and marked price is 2:3 and ratio of percentage profit and percentage discount is 3:2. What is the discount percentage

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

> The ratio of cost price and marked price is 2:3 and ratio of percentage profit and percentage discount is 3:2. What is the discount percentage

What I Did:-

Let cost price= 200
and Marked price= 300
 Let selling price be y

$(y-200/200*100)/(y-d/100*300)=3/2$
But this is not helping me to find the discount percentage. How to do it? Please help

Comment: I can't make any sense out of the last equation. The line before it looks OK, with a known cost price and marked price and unknown selling price. Perhaps if you work up the pieces of the equation one step at a time, being careful to keep track of what it is that you are representing at each step, it will work out better.

Answer (score 0):

You are off to a good start.  Let's use 100 and 150 instead of $200 and $300.  The problem gives us really nice #s to work with.

Profit % means (1+P) x C = new price N.  Discount means (1-D) x old price = new price. And we know old price = 1.5 x C and P = 1.5 x D
so using C = $100 we get 100 (1+P)= N  
and (1- 2/3P) x $150 = N 
100 + 100p = 150 - 100p
50 = 200P, or p = 25%

So new price = $125, and profit $ = 25 and discount $ = 25
25% x 100 = 3/2 x 16.6667% x 150